# How to convert round number to decimal point number in pdf invoice

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, pdf

How to convert round number to decimal point number in pdf invoice.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How to change all total as same as display in first images total?

Comment: Sub total should b display as like$34 to $33.95